# Why is term not evaluating to a function taking 0 arguments?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-c++-2008

When I try compiling

```
template<bool val>
struct boolean { static const bool value = val; };

template<typename T>
struct is_callable : boolean<sizeof((*(T*)0)()) >= 0> { };            // error!

int main(void) { bool b = is_callable<int (*)()>::value; }
```

I get:

```
error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments  
    see reference to class template instantiation 'is_callable<T>' being compiled
```

I'm pretty sure `int (*)()` is callable with `0` arguments... so why doesn't this compile?

Comment: @KerrekSB: Huh, that's quite interesting... I tried it with VC 2010 and it also gave an error. Is it a bug then? I can't tell, since there's a null pointer getting dereferenced, but practically speaking I don't see anything wrong with it...

Comment: There's no dereference. `sizeof` does not evaluate its argument.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the use of `int()`.  You can completely remove that from the example and get the same error.  The problem is the `sizeof` expression itself when used as a non-type template argument.  Example

```
template<bool val>
struct boolean { };

template<typename T>
struct is_callable : boolean<sizeof((*(T*)0)()) >= 0>  // Error
{ 
  void Test() 
  {
    auto x = sizeof((*(T*)0)()) >= 0;  // Compiles
  }

};
```

Hopefully another C++ guy can come along and determine if this `sizeof` expression is simply illegal as a type argument or if this is just a limitation in the MS C++ compiler.

Comment: There's no "type" argument here. `val` is a *non-type* parameter.

Comment: @KerrekSB doh. Corrected to say "template argument".

Comment: It's still a *non-type* template argument.

Comment: `val` is a value template argument. The result of `sizeof` is a value. That doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: @SionSheevok Nitpick: There is no such thing as a value template argument. There are only 3 types of arguments: type, non-type and template. (14.3)

Comment: @pmr you'd think type and non-type would cover the full spectrum :)

Answer (score 0):

For me this works.

```
    typedef int (*X)();

    template<typename T>
    struct is_callable : boolean<sizeof((*(X*)(T*)0)()) >= 0> { };            // works!
```

So, it looks like the compiler is not sure that you will always pass a function pointer to T when you instantiate the template class !. So, force the compiler with an explicit cast.

[Edit] : Also, on further thinking, I don't understand what you are really trying to do. Are you trying to measure the size of a function pointer which takes a single parameter? How this is going to be different for functions with different return types? Why do you need template at all for a constant expression (which is sizeof(void*))?

Please check this thread for more understanding
[What is guaranteed about the size of a function pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941793/what-is-guaranteed-about-the-size-of-a-function-pointer)

Answer (score 0):

You could just use simple template specialization.

```
#include <stdio.h>

template<typename T>
struct func_with_zero_args { static const bool value = false; };
template<>
struct func_with_zero_args <int (*)()> { static const bool value = true; };

#define STRINGIFY(t) "" #t
#define TEST(t) printf(STRINGIFY(t) ": %s\n", (func_with_zero_args<t>::value ? "yes" : "no"));

int
main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    TEST(void);
    TEST(void (*)(void));
    TEST(void (*)(int));
    TEST(int (*)(void));
    TEST(int (*)(int));
    return 0;
}
```

Generates (using g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1) 4.7.3)

```
void: no
void (*)(void): no
void (*)(int): no
int (*)(void): yes
int (*)(int): no
```