# Why function pointers are infinitely dereferenciable?

Tags: c, pointers

Coming from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915797/calling-a-function-through-its-address-in-memory-in-c-c) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22058122/why-can-we-dereference-a-function-pointer), it seems to me that dereferencing a pointer is like asking what value an address contains to which the pointer is pointing to, but I cannot understand the same in this case:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void function(){
    printf("Hello\n");
}

int main(){
    typedef void func(void);
    func* x = &function;
    printf("%p %p %p %p\n", (void *)***********x, (void *)******x, (void *)*****x, (void *)x);
}
```

which when compiled and run by `gcc tests.c; ./a.out` produces:

```
0x55b286fd8149 0x55b286fd8149 0x55b286fd8149 0x55a295e95149
```

My main question is how these can be apparently infinitely dereferenciable?

*Although not necessary, but it would be helpful in understanding if answer is made commenting on why all these addresses are same?*

Comment: Would adding a question on how to identify whether a memory location contains specfic type of invokable functions be a "separate question"?

Comment: Yes, this is a separate issue.

Answer (score 1):

A function is implicitly convertible to a pointer to itself. E.g. `func* x = function;` is legal.

So, when you dereference `x` the second time, the function resulting from the previous dereference is converted to a pointer to itself, which is then deferenced again.