# What can a char * pointer point to (is it like void *)?

Tags: c, pointers

I am using a library that contains this code (I have cut out irrelevant parts)

```
// Represents user-defined data
typedef char* aiUserData;

...

struct aiFile
{
    // Callback to write to a file
    aiFileReadProc ReadProc;

    // Callback to retrieve the current position of 
    //  the file cursor (ftell())
    aiFileTellProc TellProc;

    ...

    // User-defined, opaque data
    aiUserData UserData;
};
```

I need to use the last struct attribute `UserData`. It would be convenient to use a struct for the purpose, however as one can see in the first line UserData is declared type `char *`. I read somewhere that `char *` is similar to `void *`. Does that mean that I can do something like:

```
.UserData = &MyDataStruct;
```

Or is this not safe?

Comment: That's definitely a bug, an opaque pointer in C should always be `void *`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Character pointer is allowed to alias to any other pointer type.

If you cast your `.UserData` pointer to the correct type( typeof MyDataStruct ), you can use the object it points to.

You are also allowed to dereference a character pointer without casting as long as the pointer points to valid memory. What value the memory holds is another matter and you should use it correctly.

And a quote why is it allowed:

> 6.5. p7 An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of
>   the following types:
>
> — a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
>
> — a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
>
> — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective type of the
>   object,
>
> — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a qualified version of the
>   effective type of the object,
>
> — an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its
>   members (including, recursively, a member of a subaggregate or contained union), or
>
> — **a character type**.

And:

> 6.2.5. p28 A pointer to void shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a
>   pointer to a character type
>
> 6.3.2.3. p1 A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any object type. A pointer to
>   any object type may be converted to a pointer to void and back again; the result shall
>   compare equal to the original pointer.

Therefore a char pointer can store a pointer of any type, the same way as a void pointer.

Of course as you mention with your reference, none of this holds true for function pointers. You cannot mix them and other types.

Comment: I read C99 spec, section 6.2.5, paragraph 27, its too long to post in a comment, but my concern is that it does not explicitly specify that a pointer to char is compatible with a pointer to struct. (Similar to the fact that function pointers are not always compatible with pointers to data). What do you think?

Comment: But it can not store pointer to a function as indicated by the accepted answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941793/what-is-guaranteed-about-the-size-of-a-function-pointer right? I guess that's why the standart specifies that `An object shall ...`. A function is not an object so its pointer may be of a different size which void * or char * would not be able to hold.

Comment: @user10607 That is something completely different. Why didn't you ask that in your question? If that is the problem you already have your answer.

Comment: No that is not the problem, but I just wanted to understand what is going on.

Comment: @user10607 Ok, I though only that was the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The library is badly designed, it should be a `void *`.

You can legally convert any pointer to/from `void *`, and convert `void *` to/from `char *`, so it's safe.

When setting the pointer, you must cast to `char *`:

```
static struct mydata {
  float pi;
} data; /* This is what we want to store. */

struct aiFile whatever;
whatever.UserData = (char *) &data;
```

and later when you want to use the pointer, you must do the inverse cast:

```
struct mydata *d = (struct mydata *) whatever.UserData;
```

In practice you'd of course `typedef` your `struct mydata` too; I omitted it for brevity.

If the library had done the right thing and used `void *`, none of the casting would be necessary.

Comment: Oh so I have to cast it back before each usage? That's unexpected, I think you just saved me a lot of frustration right there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can assume that's safe.

It is suggested to hold "user data", so we can assume that the underlying library isn't going to use it, and you can pass a pointer to whatever you like:

```
.UserData = (char *)&MyDataStruct;
```

It's entirely up to you to interpret it correctly at the other end, i.e., in this case as your data structure.

Comment: It seems that @2501 is suggesting to do `.UserData = (struct MyStruct *) MyDataStruct`. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: I guess it depends how strict your compiler is on checking types.

Comment: @user10607 The cast is different when setting the pointer in the library's struct, and when *using* that pointer for your purposes, of course.