# Is (int *)0 a null pointer?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, null-pointer

This could be thought of as an extension to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16563114/912144) (I'm interested in C only, but adding C++ to complete the extension)

The C11 standard at 6.3.2.3.3 says:

> An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type `void *`, is called a null pointer constant.

What my take on this personally is that `0` and `(void *)0` represent the null pointer, whose integer value may not actually be 0, but that doesn't cover 0 cast to any other type.

But, the standard then continues:

> If a null pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a *null pointer*, ...

which covers `(int *)0` as null pointer since cast is an *explicit conversion* (C11, 6.3) which is listed under conversion methods.

However, what still makes me wonder is the following phrase

> ... or such an expression cast to type `void *` ...

With the above semantics, this phrase seems completely useless. The question is, is this phrase completely useless? If not, what implications does it have? Consequently, is `(int *)0` the null pointer or not?

---

Another question that can help the discussion is the following. Is `(long long)123` considered "123 converted to `long long`", or "123 with type `long long`". In other words, is there any conversion in `(long long)123`? If there is none, then the second quote above *doesn't* cover `(int *)0` as a null pointer.

Comment: Might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597142/when-was-the-null-macro-not-0

Comment: `(int*)0` is **a** null pointer, not *the*

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, you are right, but since _Any two null pointers shall compare equal_ (C11, 6.3.2.3-4), it wouldn't really make much difference differentiating between them.

Comment: You might like to look at my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889541/issue-with-null-pointers-on-harvard-architecture-platform

Comment: @Shahbaz: Well, it all depends. Is a null `int*` the same as a null `double*`? I guess in C that is the case...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Short answer:

In both C and C++, `(int *)0` is a constant expression whose value is a null pointer.  It is not, however, a *null pointer constant*.  The only observable difference between a constant-expression-whose-value-is-a-null-pointer and a null-pointer-constant, that I know of, is that a null-pointer-constant can be assigned to an lvalue of any pointer type, but a constant-expression-whose-value-is-a-null-pointer has a specific pointer type and can only be assigned to an lvalue with a compatible type.  In C, but not C++, `(void *)0` is also a null pointer constant; this is a special case for `void *` consistent with the general C-but-not-C++ rule that `void *` is assignment compatible with any other pointer-to-object type.

For example:

```c
long *a = 0;           // ok, 0 is a null pointer constant
long *b = (long *)0;   // ok, (long *)0 is a null pointer with appropriate type
long *c = (void *)0;   // ok in C, invalid conversion in C++
long *d = (int *)0;    // invalid conversion in both C and C++
```

And here's a case where the difference between the null pointer constant `(void *)0` and a constant-expression-whose-value-is-a-null-pointer with type `void *` is visible, even in C:

```
typedef void (*fp)(void);  // any pointer-to-function type will show this effect

fp a = 0;                  // ok, null pointer constant
fp b = (void *)0;          // ok in C, invalid conversion in C++
fp c = (void *)(void *)0;  // invalid conversion in both C and C++
```

Also, it's moot nowadays, but since you brought it up: *No matter what* the bit representation of `long *`'s null pointer is, all of these assertions behave as indicated by the comments:

```
// 'x' is initialized to a null pointer
long *x = 0;

// 'y' is initialized to all-bits-zero, which may or may not be the
// representation of a null pointer; moreover, it might be a "trap
// representation", UB even to access
long *y;
memset(&y, 0, sizeof y);

assert (x == 0);         // must succeed
assert (x == (long *)0); // must succeed
assert (x == (void *)0); // must succeed in C, unspecified behavior in C++
assert (x == (int *)0);  // invalid comparison in both C and C++

assert (memcmp(&x, &y, sizeof y) == 0); // unspecified

assert (y == 0);         // UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR: y may be a trap representation
assert (y == x);         // UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR: y may be a trap representation
```

"Unspecified" comparisons do not provoke undefined behavior, but the standard doesn't say whether they evaluate true or false, and the implementation is not required to document which of the two it is, or even to pick one and stick to it.  It would be perfectly valid for the above `memcmp` to alternate between returning 0 and 1 if you called it many times.

---

Long answer with standard quotes:

To understand what a *null pointer constant* is, you first have to understand what an *integer constant expression* is, and that's pretty hairy -- a complete understanding requires you to read sections 6.5 and 6.6 of C99 in detail.  This is my summary:

- A *constant expression* is any C expression which the compiler can evaluate to a constant without knowing the value of any object (`const` or otherwise; however, `enum` values are fair game), and which has no side effects.  (This is a drastic simplification of roughly 25 pages of standardese and may not be exact.)
- *Integer constant expressions* are a restricted subset of constant expressions, conveniently defined in a single paragraph, C99 6.6p6 and its footnote:

  > An integer constant expression<sup>96</sup> shall have integer type and shall only have operands that are integer constants, enumeration constants, character constants, `sizeof` expressions whose results are integer constants, and floating constants that are the immediate operands of casts. Cast operators in an integer constant expression shall only convert arithmetic types to integer types, except as part of an operand to the `sizeof`
  > operator.

  > <sup>96</sup> An integer constant expression is used to specify the size of a bit-field member of a structure, the value of an enumeration constant, the size of an array, or the value of a case constant. Further constraints that apply to the integer constant expressions used in [`#if`] are discussed in 6.10.1.

  For purpose of this discussion, the important bit is

  > Cast operators ... shall only convert arithmetic types to integer types

  which means that `(int *)0` is *not* an *integer* constant expression, although it is a constant expression.

The C++98 definition appears to be more or less equivalent, modulo C++ features and deviations from C.  For instance, the stronger separation of character and boolean types from integer types in C++ means that the C++ standard speaks of "*integral* constant expressions" rather than "*integer* constant expressions", and then sometimes requires not just an integral constant expression, but an integral constant expression *of integer type*, excluding `char`, `wchar_t`, and `bool` (and maybe also `signed char` and `unsigned char`? it's not clear to me from the text).

Now, the C99 definition of *null pointer constant* is what this question is all about, so I'll repeat it: 6.3.2.3p3 says

> An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type
> `void *`, is called a *null pointer constant*. If a null pointer constant is converted to a
> pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a *null pointer*, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function.

Standardese is very, very literal.  Those two sentences mean exactly the same thing as:

> An integer constant expression with the value 0 is called a *null pointer constant*.
> An integer constant expression with the value 0, cast to type `void *`, is **also** a *null pointer constant*.
> When **any** null pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting pointer is called a *null pointer* and is guaranteed to compare unequal ...

(Italics - definition of term. Boldface - my emphasis.)  So what that means is, in C, `(long *)0` and `(long *)(void *)0` are two ways of writing exactly the same thing, namely the null pointer with type `long *`.

C++ is different. The equivalent text is C++98 4.10 [conv.ptr]:

> A *null pointer constant* is an integral constant expression (5.19) rvalue of integer type that evaluates to zero.

That's all.  "Integral constant expression rvalue of integer type" is very nearly the same thing as C99's "integer constant expression", but there are a few things that qualify in C but not C++: for instance, in C the character literal `'\x00'` is an integer constant expression, and therefore a null pointer constant, but in C++ it is *not* an integral constant expression of integer type, so it is not a null pointer constant either.

More to the point, though, C++ doesn't have the "or such an expression cast to `void *`" clause.  That means that `((void *)0)` is **not** a null pointer constant in C++.  It is still a *null pointer*, but it is not assignment compatible with any other pointer type.  This is consistent with C++'s generally pickier type system.

---

C++ 2011 and C 2023 both revised the concept of "null pointer", adding a special type for them (`nullptr_t`) and a new keyword which evaluates to a null pointer constant (`nullptr`). I do not fully understand the changes and am not going to try to explain them, but I am pretty sure that a bare `0` is still a valid null pointer constant in both.

Comment: I would appreciate it if you would mention which standard you're talking about, i.e. C or C++. Also, can you give an example of a constant expression that can have `(void *)0` but not `(int *)0`?

Comment: C, specifically C99; I have not read C11 yet, and I do not remember offhand whether `(void *)0` is still a null pointer *constant* in C++.  There *are* differences between C and C++ in this area, for instance `NULL` is *not* allowed to expand to `((void *)0)` in C++.

Comment: @Zack Both C and C++ require `NULL` to be a null pointer constant. In C99 this includes `(void *)0`, but C++ defines a null pointer constant as "an integral constant expression rvalue of integer type that evaluates to
zero."

Comment: @DKrueger I couldn't remember if C++ excluded `((void *)0)` from the definition of a null pointer constant, or if it just said that `NULL` was not allowed to expand to that expression.  It seems it was the former.

Comment: I'm not sure why `fp c = (void *)(void *)0` is invalid. Can anyone explain?

Comment: @iBug Because there is no implicit conversion from `void *` to any pointer-to-function type, and the double cast to `void *` makes the right-hand side of the assignment not be a _null pointer constant_ (even though it is still a _constant expression whose value is a null pointer_), so the implicit conversion of null pointer constants to _any_ pointer type is also unavailable. `fp c = (fp)(void *)(void *)0` would be valid again.

Comment: @zwol, just a small detail. `(void *)(void *)0` is not a null-pointer-constant, but something like `int *x = (void *)(void *)0;` is still fine. That's just the usual `void *` to `any *` assignment that's allowed in C. I haven't verified with the standard, but `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic` actually singles out *function pointers* where assignment from `void *` is invalid: _warning: ISO C forbids initialization between function pointer and 'void *' \[-Wpedantic\]_. Your point is still correct though, just wanted to point this out.

Comment: @Shahbaz Yes, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47446430/how-can-converting-a-pointer-to-void-twice-be-invalid/47446963#47446963 for a bunch of further exposition on this point.

Comment: @zwol Sir, don't you have a conflict btw first and third examples. In first you said, _long *d = (int *)0;    // invalid conversion in both C and C++_ but in third one _assert (x == (int *)0);  // must succeed in C, unspecified in C++_ ?? If not, why? Would you mind explaining?

Comment: @zwol and my english is not very well as yours, what do you mean by saying "trap" and "trap representation" in this context?

Comment: @snr First question: That's an error, thank you for noticing. I will correct the answer.  Second question: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725809/trap-representation/6725981 .

Answer (score 12):

Evaluating the expression `(int*)0` yields a null pointer of type `int*`.

`(int*)0` is not a *null pointer constant*.

A *null pointer constant* is a particular kind of expression that may appear in C source code. A *null pointer* is a value that may occur in a running program.

C and C++ (being two distinct languages) have slightly different rules in this area. C++ doesn't have the "or such an expression cast to type `void*`" wording. But I don't think that affects the answer to your question.

As for your question about `(long long)123`, I'm not sure how it's related, but the expression `123` is of type `int`, and the cast specifies a conversion from `int` to `long long`.

I think the core confusion is an assumption that the cast in `(int*)0` does not specify a conversion, since `0` is already a *null pointer constant*. But a *null pointer constant* is not necessarily an expression of pointer type. In particular, the expression `0` is both a *null pointer constant* and an expression of type `int`; it is not of any pointer type. The term *null pointer constant* needs to be thought of as a single concept, not a phrase whose meaning depends on the individual words that make it up.

Comment: However (using GCC-4.8.1/MinGW-32 under Windows 7) `(int *)0 == NULL` does appear to evaluate to `1` (i.e. true). So it does compare equal to a null pointer constant. Is this standard or implementation-defined?

Comment: I fixed the case of `NULL`. But is that your answer to a `[language-lawyer]` tag, or should I be expecting 10 edits per minute before starting to read the answer?

Comment: @Kninnug Yes, that is standard, but by virtue of a different section of the standard: the definition of `==` says that all null pointers compare equal, regardless of their precise type.

Comment: @KeithThompson, I'm sorry, I saw a two line answer (which is not very precise and standard-quoting!) and I thought you may be one of them [fastest gun in the west](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9731/169090) people.

Comment: @n.m., I have no quarrel with that. But is `(int *)0` a null pointer? Keith says yes, but no reference or reasoning is given with that. He might as well be just giving his personal opinion.

Comment: @Shahbaz: You quoted the relevant portion of the standard yourself. `0` is a *null pointer constant*. Converting it to any pointer type yields a *null pointer*.

Comment: @KeithThompson, that's where the second question comes in. If `(long long)123` is an `int` converted to `long long`, then yes `(int *)0` is a null pointer converted to `int *`. But if `(long long)123` is straightforward a `long long` number with value 123 (no conversion involved), then `(int *)0` would also be a pointer of `int *` with value 0. I'm searching in the standard for this myself.

Comment: In both cases, the cast specifies a noon-trivial conversion. Although `0` is a *null pointer constant*, it's still of type `int`. There is no `int*` with the value `0`, since `0` is not of type `int*`.