# How can converting a pointer to `void*` twice be invalid?

Tags: c, pointers, type-conversion, language-lawyer

Regarding [*zwol*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21387175/5958455), I'm confused why

> ```
> typedef void (*fp)(void);  // any pointer-to-function type will show this effect
>
> fp c = (void *)(void *)0;  // invalid conversion in both C and C++
> ```

How is the last line invalid? To me, it sounds like converting `int(0)` to `void*` twice, where converting a pointer to the same type should be absolutely fine, like this:

```
int a, *pa = (int*)&a;
//           ^^^^^^ Totally OK
```

Comment: Probably compiler dependent, gcc doesn't mind

Comment: @ringø What's the standard's specification?

Comment: I don't think the other question is saying that `(void *)(void *)` is an invalid conversion in general. What he's saying is that it doesn't meet the criteria to be a **null pointer constant**.

Comment: Converting a pointer to object (`void *`) into a pointer to function (`void (*)(void *)`) is not guaranteed to be reversible , nor vice versa.

Comment: @ringø With `-Wpedantic` you should get an error message along the lines of " warning: ISO C forbids initialization between function pointer and ‘void *’".

Comment: in his answer, the conversion he's talking about is the one that is implicit in the assignment, not the sequence of casts used to produce the operand.

Comment: Are you sure that you used 'c' compiler, not 'c++'. There should be no problem with 'c'. There would be a problem with 'c++'. The latter would not allow you to assigh 'void*' to the function pointer.

Comment: @Serge The original answer states it's *Invalid in both C and C++*.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure. In this case you have a faulty 'c' compiler.

Comment: The part of the code `(void *)(void *)0` is valid. The problem is that it is not a valid initializer for a function pointer.

Comment: Is it a C or C++ question?

Comment: @curiousguy Both, as the original answer is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing you're asking about was a contrived example, meant to illustrate a corner case of the rules of C, and the thing that's invalid isn't the double cast, it's the assignment.

If you have any pointer-to-function type, such as

```
typedef void (*fp)(void);
```

you can initialize variables of this type with any valid *null pointer constant*, e.g.

```
fp a = 0;          // canonical null pointer constant in C
fp b = (void *)0;  // another common choice
fp c = '\0';       // yes, really, this is a null pointer constant
fp d = (1-1);      // and so is this
```

But you *can't* initialize them with a pointer to any specific type other than `fp` itself, even if that pointer is a null pointer, and even if the specific type in question is `void *`.

```
char *x = 0;
void *y = 0;
fp e = x;     // invalid: no assignment conversion from `char *` to `fp`
fp f = y;     // invalid: no assignment conversion from `void *` to `fp`
```

The line from my old answer that you were confused by,

```
fp g = (void *)(void *)0;
```

is essentially the same as `fp f = y` above.  The right-hand side of both assignments is a null pointer with type `void *`, but *not* a null pointer *constant*, so the *assignment* is invalid.

You are probably now wondering why `(void *)(void *)0` isn't a null pointer constant, even though `(void *)0` is a null pointer constant.  This is just the way the C standard happens to be written: a null pointer constant is defined as any integer constant expression with value 0, possibly with *one* cast to `void *` in front of it.  Any extra casts and it's no longer a null pointer constant (but is still a constant expression).  (Integer constant expressions cannot contain internal casts to pointer types.)

In your contrasting example

```
int a;
int *pa = (int *)&a;
```

no null pointers are involved, and no integer constant expressions either, and the cast really is 100% redundant.  `&a` could be a constant expression (if and only if `a` has static storage duration), but it is not an *integer* constant expression.

Comment: ===> (0-0) <===

Comment: Thanks I got it. The invalid conversion is `void*` -> `void(*)(void)`, not the null constant to `void*`.

Comment: @Stargateur That's a great emoji