# Why cast zero to pointer type and access its member work?

Tags: c, gcc

Recently, I saw something cool.

```
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({                      \
const typeof( ((type *)0)->member ) *__mptr = (ptr);    \
(type *)( (char *)__mptr - offsetof(type,member) );})
```

Basically, I know what this macro does. But there is one thing I can't understand.

Why can we cast `0` into pointer type ( struct ) and access its member ? I have already [referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21386995/is-int-0-a-null-pointer) some similar stuff and `0` seems like a null pointer. So why can we cast a null pointer and then access its member?

Comment: I'll leave the full answer to the language lawyers, but the short answer is: We don't access its member. We only take the `typeof` that member. This is a compile-time operation that doesn't do any pointer dereferencing at runtime.

Comment: The term you are looking for is *unevaluated context*.

Comment: This link has a good explanation https://radek.io/2012/11/10/magical-container_of-macro/

Comment: BTW, the nonstandard parts of the macro, which facilitate a type check, aren't even needed. The typecheck can be done perfectly within the bounds of the standard: `((type *)( (char *)(0? &(type){0}.member : (ptr)) - offsetof(type,member) ))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`typeof` is a gcc extension.  The result of this operator is a type name.

This works because its operand is evaluated at compile time, so a pointer need not actually point to anything.  The [documentation for this operator](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html#Typeof) states:

> The operand of `typeof` is evaluated for its side effects if and only if it is an expression of variably modified type or the name of such a type.

Since a `struct` can't contain a variable length array, this guarantees `typeof( ((type *)0)->member )` will not be evaluated at run time, so this is a safe operation.

Answer (score 0):

In the code sample you list, it is casting 0 within `typeof`.  But `typeof` is not a function, it is an operator.  You are accessing the type of it and not the value of it.

Reference this question:  [Why is typeof null "object"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808226/why-is-typeof-null-object)