Status of pointer variables in a struct after using malloc
Here is my struct definition:
struct Node{
    void *data;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;
};

If I allocate memory for this struct using malloc(), will the pointer variables be NULL?
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    Node *node = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    if(node->left == NULL){
        //Is it guaranteed to be NULL?
    }
    return 0;
}


This question is similar to: Difference between malloc and calloc?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

What does the documentation of malloc say?

If you want it to be null, use calloc instead.

calloc isn't guaranteed to initialize pointers to NULL, or initialize floating point objects to 0, but it will do both on the vast majority of platforms (just not on some very obscure platforms where the binary representation of null pointers or zero floating point values is not all bytes zero).

Section 7.22.3.4 (C23 7.24.3.6) The malloc Function
The standard states:

#include <stdlib.h>
void *malloc(size_t size);

Description
The malloc function allocates space for an object whose size is
specified by size and whose value is indeterminate.

It means that the content of the memory allocated by malloc cannot be determined.

   //Is it guaranteed to be NULL?


No, it is not and assuming it may invoke undefined behaviour.

When referring to the ISO C standard, it is generally a good idea to specify to which version of the standard you are referring. It appears that you are not referring to the latest published version of the standard (which is C23), as the correct section number is 7.24.3.6 in that version of the standard.

@AndreasWenzel added remark about C23. I do not have an access to C23

On top of other points made, you should get in the habit of verifying malloc succeeded before dereferencing the pointer it returns. Also, freeing your dynamically allocated memory.
E.g.
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Node *node = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    if (!node) {
        // Print error message if you like
        return 1;
    }

    if (node->left == NULL) {
        //Is it guaranteed to be NULL?
    }

    free(node);

    return 0;
}


It is the correct way, but it can be useless on modern systems as they use an optimistic allocation strategy and will allocate the memory when it is touched. If no memory the program will fail anyway.


If I allocate memory for this struct using malloc, will the pointer variables be NULL?

No this is not true, you have to assign the variables yourself. I would point to newly allocated memory (generally there is some garbage value in there).
P.S. malloc gives you an un-initialized buffer however calloc provides you 0ed memory.

However, all zeros might not be the same as NULL pointer... See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63611182/107090
